# Obtener datos correctos con mysql

Tags: mysqli

necesito hacer una consulta mysqli que tome los datos que necesito de 3 tablas...es decir que cuando le doy 'ntb' en el buscador de mi navbar me traiga los datos relacionados a esa palabra que estén 'habilitados'...la cosa que en la consulta que tengo me trae los productos 'habilitados' y otros que no lo están. A continuación les pongo la consulta que tengo.

```
SELECT T1.id_art, T1.marca, T1.estadoArt, T1.envio, T1.destaque, T2.precio_final, T2.dolar, T2.ganancias, T2.descuento, T3.descripcion, T3.stock_disponible, T3.precio_ct, T3.tipo_iva  FROM articulos T1 
                            INNER JOIN art_precio T2 ON T1.id_art = T2.id_art_precio 
                            INNER JOIN art_proveedor T3 ON T1.id_art = T3.cod 
                            WHERE T1.art_grupo LIKE '%ntb%' || T1.art_subgrupo LIKE '%ntb%' 
                            || T1.marca LIKE '%ntb%' || T3.descripcion LIKE '%ntb%'
                            AND (T3.stock_disponible > 4 && T3.precio_ct != 0 && T1.estadoArt = 'habilitado')
```

Comment: Se agradece un ejemplo mínimo y verificable que incluya un set de datos, de modo que se pueda reproducir el problema.